# Perforce,Do "need to resolve" message always imply pending changes?

Tags: perforce

Perforce on linux...
Server version: P4D/LINUX26X86_64/2013.2/938876 (2014/09/23)
(I know, its old, beyond my control)

I sync my branch to a specific CL on a source branch using...

```
% p4 integrate //a/b/main/...@950828 ...
% p4 resolve -at
% p4 submit
```

I think I don't need to "p4 sync" my workarea to what I just synced to with the integrate, but I did that as well (can't hurt ?)

I bring some changes in from a different CL of the same source branch with an unshelve...

```
% p4_unshelve -b a-branch-spec -s 950891
```

That appears to have gone OK given the messages...

```
- Unshelved Files -
//a/b/branches/my_brahcn/x/y/z/configs_old.dj  (delete)  (rev: none)

- Messages -
//a/b/branches/x/RHEL6.tcsh - must resolve //a/b/main/RHEL6.tcsh@=950891 before submitting
//a/b/branches/x/w/v/env.cfg - must resolve //a/b/main/w/v/env.cfg@=950891 before submitting   
-I- Successfully completed p4 unshelve
```

Reading the message about the need to resolve, I try that...

```
% p4 resolve
No file(s) to resolve.
```

Hmmmm...   I must resolve these changes, but there's nothing to resolve ?
p4 opened shows nothing...

```
% p4 opened
File(s) not opened on this client.
```

Q: What's going on here ?

Also, if I sync my branch to an even earlier changelist on the source branch using the integrate/resolve-at/submit method, does my branch still have the changes from the later CL I synced to before?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Do “need to resolve” message always imply pending changes?

Yes.

> Q: What's going on here ?

Your `p4_unshelve` script isn't using the same `P4CLIENT` as the regular `p4` commands you're running in the shell.

(This is a bit of a shot in the dark but it's the easiest explanation for the completely inconsistent results between the two sets of output.)

Comment: The script was using the same workarea.  Don't know why it didn't work.  Maybe it's because I was using p4perl  ?  Could that be it ?  Anyway, that was at the heart of the problem.  Thanks